# android manifest for Nexus 7 tablet

Tags: android, manifest, apk, google-play, signing

I have application apk file and I want it to be available in Google Play for Nexus 7 tablet. Unfortunatelly, after uploading Google says this apk is not compatible with Nexus 7. I saw other developers solving this problem by "softening" camera permission in manifest. For me this does not work. My manifest looks as follows. Any hints are appreciated.
Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="xxx.yyy.zzz"
  android:versionCode="12"
  android:versionName="1.2.2"
  android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" 
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/zenfolio_icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name" 
             android:name=".ZenfolioApplication" 
             android:theme="@style/ZenfolioAppTheme" 
             android:debuggable="false"></application></manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add also this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring relevant sub-features (flash, autofocus) with `required="false"` as well. BTW, is this the whole manifest?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this in your manifest :

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

**EDIT2:** keep this, and remove the `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>` completely from your `Manifest`.

Comment: I think this isn't the problem. He just want to use camera permission with the nexus